# CSS style based on value of ACF

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using WordPress with ACF, and I need to use a value of custom fields for CSS. For example, if the value of ACF 'Name' is YES, then CSS style just background around that field, if the value of the field is NO, then the background will be red.

Comment: Can you please add what you have try so far?

Comment: I use ACF for products, I have one field name is : ''WiFi''. Some products have value YES, some have value NO for that field. I want to diplay on product page where is value YES (green background aroung that text), and red where is value NO

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily fix it by if condition. It has value then shows green color otherwise shows red color. you need to replace the CSS class name.

```
<?php
// Get field data
$data = get_field('wifi');
if( 'yes' == $data ){
    ?>
    <style>
        .entry-title{
            color: green;
        }   
    </style>
    <?php
}else{
        ?>
    <style>
        .entry-title{
            color: red;
        }   
    </style>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Field: https://prnt.sc/cWvtiZia1KCm 
Green value: https://prnt.sc/ZO_4N_ob6J7h 
Red value: https://prnt.sc/ApikklLCEhhz

Answer (score 0):

I would do it via classes.

Supposing "WiFi" is a "True/False" custom field:

```css
.no_wifi {
    background-color: red;
}
.wifi {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<?php
   $class_to_add = 'no_wifi';
   if (get_field('WiFi')) {
       $class_to_add = "wifi";
   }
?>

<div class="<?php echo $class_to_add; ?>">
    ...
</div>
```